# Windows 8 not showing up in GRUB menu

Tags: windows, linux, terminal, fedora, grub

My computer is pretty new and has a UEFI setup. I have secure boot off, fast boot off, and am booting in Legacy mode. I got Fedora 17 to install and now it is set up and working correctly, however I can no longer access my Windows 8 installation. If I go to files in Fedora I can still see all my data from Windows on my hard drive, and I would just like to have the ability to access both Fedora and Windows 8, help would be greatly appreciated! The results from `fdisk -l` are as follows:

> `WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util
>   fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.`
>
> `Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes 255 heads, 63
>   sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x377e5c45`
>
> `Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System /dev/sda1 * 1 1465149167
>   732574583+ ee GPT Partition 1 does not start on physical sector
>   boundary.`
>
> `Disk /dev/mapper/vgisaac-lvswap: 7784 MB, 7784628224 bytes 255 heads,
>   63 sectors/track, 946 cylinders, total 15204352 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096
>   bytes`
>
> `Disk /dev/mapper/vgisaac-lvroot: 7784 MB, 7784628224 bytes 255 heads,
>   63 sectors/track, 946 cylinders, total 15204352 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096
>   bytes`

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not support booting on GPT partitioned disks when on BIOS systems. I would guess that using the legacy BIOS mode on a UEFI system also leads to this problem. You may want to switch to non-legacy mode (which would probably require tweaking partitions and reinstalling GRUB).

That said, you could try simply regenerating the GRUB config files. Make sure os-prober exists, then run

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

If that successfully detects Windows and makes a Windows entry, but Windows fails to boot, you'll probably have to switch to MBR partitioning or switch to UEFI mode (non-legacy).

See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2?rd=Grub2#Updating_GRUB_2_configuration_on_BIOS_systems

As a side note, for GPT partitioned disks, you should use `gdisk -l /dev/sda` rather than `fdisk -l`.